# No module named csv

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, mercurial

Using

- Windows 7
- Mercurial 3.4.1 with Python 2.7.9

The python script (below) produces the following console output when executing `hg dummy` in a console windows.

```
start reading file
abort: No module named csv!
```

Here is the python script:

```
import csv
import sys

def dummy(ui, repo, node, **opts)
  with open('file.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    print 'start reading file'
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    print 'finished reading file'

cmdtable = {
  'dummy': (dummy, 
  [('', '', None, '')], '',)
}
```

Tried using absolute path to csv file but that did not help.

All online examples use 'import csv' and that appears to work.

What is causing this issue? Does python come by default with csv support or is this addon?

Comment: run `pip list` and check if csv is there!

Comment: @SIslam `csv` is a builtin module and so `pip list` will not show it.

Comment: @Lars have you used the variable `csv` or called a file `csv.py` somewhere?

Comment: Ah! then try help()>modules

Comment: Ffisegydd: No csv variable or file called csv.py is used.

Comment: How did you set up `hg` to run `dummy` as a command?  Put `print sys.path` right after the imports to see where it looks for modules.

Answer (score 1):

Python does come with csv support.  I used `print sys.path` as alexis recommended and found that Mercurial referenced `..\Program Files\TortoiseHg\library.zip` instead of the actual Python installation folder.  Copying `csv.py` from the Python installation folder into the Mercurial `library.zip` file resolved the issue.

Answer (score -1):

The module name is csv not CSV.